# Graphite / Grafana: How to modify a metric's resolution in a query?

Tags: grafana, metrics, graphite

I have a metric with a resolution of 3h (let's call it `series.a`) and another one with resolution 4h (`series.b`).  I want to combine the two (e. g. build their sum).  The naive approach (`sum("series.a", "series.b")`) gives me a metric which has values values only at the times where both series had values, i. e. one value every 12h.

I considered modifying the time series so that both are in 1h steps, e. g. by introducing artificial `null` values and then using the `keepLastValue()` function on both, prior to summing them.  But I found no function to convert a metric with 3h-resolution into a metric with 1h resolution.  Something like `realign()` or `resample()` would be nice.

A solution to this would solve several issues I have with metrics of varying resolution (due to retention policies).

I don't want to change the data on disk.  I only want to convert the metric during querying.